# Cycle through 2 classes on `html` after clicking a link/toggle

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I currently have a toggle that when clicked adds/removes a class to the `html` tag.

I'd like to update this so if you click after the original class is added the class is changed to `.new-mode` rather than removing the current class and the `html` tag being class-less. If the link is clicked again, it will then return to the default state.

So in essence it's got 3 states:

1. No class (default / on load)
2. Class One added (on 1st click)
3. Class One removed, Class Two added (on 2nd click)

Then on the next click it would return to the default state without a class. So essentially just cycling through 2 classes on click. You can see I have the 1st toggle working in my example - but I'm unsure how to target the next click(s) and I'd really appreciate some help.

```js
const html = document.querySelector('html');
const button = document.querySelector('.contrast__link');
button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  html.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
});
```

```css
html { background: white; color: black; }
.dark-mode { background: black; color: white;}
.new-mode { background: blue; color: white;}
```

```html
<p class="contrast__link">Click here</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what the current state is and handle the transition to the next state. Since you have a reference to the `html` element, you can use its [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property to see which classes are currently applied to it.

The return value is not an array, it's a `DOMTokenList`, so be sure to use [`DOMTokenList.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) instead of `Array#includes`. The collection also supports [adding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add), [removing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove), and [toggling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) one or more classes.

The simplest way to check and change the state is an `if-else` chain:

```js
const html = document.querySelector('html');
const button = document.querySelector('.contrast__link');
button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (html.classList.contains('dark-mode')) {
    html.classList.remove('dark-mode');
    html.classList.add('new-mode');
  }
  else if (html.classList.contains('new-mode')) {
    html.classList.remove('new-mode');
  }
  else {
    html.classList.add('dark-mode');
  }
});
```

```css
html { background: white; color: black; }
.dark-mode { background: black; color: white;}
.new-mode { background: blue; color: white;}
```

```html
<p class="contrast__link">Click here</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually looking into if statements for something else I'm looking at too (https://stackoverflow.com/q/73746140/1406440) so maybe this will help on that too. Quite similar but need to run/disable sections of script when a class is added to the html.